# kendoui filter event customize

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

Does anyone have any idea how to modify the look of the column in kendo grid after choosing a filter? I need to set the header of column with a filter applied more flashy.
I have found a lot of examples on customization of the filter design, but I cannot find anything to help me with this - is there an event that I can modify or a property to what happens to header after filter is turned on (and off)?
I see that there is a lot of options possible to change in filterable object, but nowhere can I find a complete reference or anything like this.

Comment: Look inside the CSS of the tables, there must be some class added to the column header when selected.

Comment: That really does help, but the problem is that with the css class (k-state-active is added) I only get the filter button, not the entire column header and I can't select parent with CSS, I need Javascript to write something like ('.k-state-active').parent().addclass...

Comment: i do not know... bump. you better try it.